# Apply Code-First migration when the project starts

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

I want to perform automatic migration when the project starts.

Code and description:
Creating a connection string to the database, and mapping database.

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var connectStr = new SqlConnectionFactory()
            .CreateConnection(new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                DataSource = "NAME-DATABASE",
                InitialCatalog = "TestDB",
                IntegratedSecurity = true,
                ApplicationName = "TestDB"
            }.ToString());
        var SessionDB = new ContentDb(connectStr);
    }
}
```

Description of the database table "TestDB", and mapping table.

```
public class File
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class FileMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<File>
{
    public FileMap()
    {
        ToTable("FILE");
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("NAME");
    }
}
```

Main class domain.

```
public class ContentDb : DbContext
{
    public ContentDb(DbConnection connection): base(connection, true)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new ContentInitializer());
        Database.Initialize(true);
    }   
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new FileMap());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Class initialization and migration

```
public class ContentInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<ContentDb>
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(ContentDb context)
    {   
        if (!context.Database.Exists() || !context.Database.CompatibleWithModel(false))
        {
            var mConfig = new DbMigrationsConfiguration();
            mConfig.TargetDatabase = new DbConnectionInfo(context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
            var migrator = new DbMigrator(mConfig);
            var migrations = migrator.GetPendingMigrations();
            if (migrations.Any())
            {
                var scriptor = new MigratorScriptingDecorator(migrator);
                string script = scriptor.ScriptUpdate(null, migrations.Last());
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(script))
                {
                    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(script);
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in [`MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829293(v=vs.113).aspx) initializer

```
Database.SetInitializer<ContentDb>(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ContentDb, 
                                           Project.Migrations.Configuration>());
using (var dB = new ContentDb(connectStr))
{
    dB.Database.Initialize(true);
}
```

If you add that to your project start-up (e.g. `Application_Start()` in `Global.asax.cs` for ASP.NET) the migrations will be applied immediately.

If you have not enabled migrations yet you can do so by executing the following in the package manager console:

> Enable-Migrations –EnableAutomaticMigrations

*NOTE:* Automatic migrations are somewhat limited and I recommend using "coded migrations". See e.g. [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621) for some details.